# svg appears clipped by css transform when nested in a div

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to apply `-webkit-transform` on an `svg` nested in a `div`.  The `svg` is larger than the `div`.  I want to shrink it down and reposition it so it appears fully contained within the `div`. The transforms are working, but wherever the `svg` was previously clipped from the `div`, it stays clipped when shrunk down.

This fiddle illustrates my problem.  After transforming, shouldn't the border appear to be all the way around the `rect`?

http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/d3yS6/

html:

```
<div>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect x="50" y="50" border="#0f0" fill="#ccc" width="300" height="300"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#f00;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
div svg {
    -webkit-transform:translate(-30px,-30px) rotate(-10deg);
    stroke-width:7px;
    stroke:#000;
}
```

Comment: No "viewbox" details?

Comment: I'm new to using svg.  I thought viewbox wasn't necessary.  Wouldn't it default to the width of what's contained in it?

Comment: "viewbox" defines the co-ordinate system which defines the boundaries of the SVG, **not the size** but I confess it's all pretty new to me too.

Comment: i just came across this explanation of viewbox: http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Making+Sense+of+SVG+viewBox's+Madness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not provided a width and height for the svg element. Per the SVG specification and the rules for replaced elements that should mean that it defaults to 300 x 150 px (see Firefox) but Chrome/Webkit has a bug which means that it defaults to the height and width of the container i.e. 100px x 100px. Chrome have plans to fix this soon.

Since the rect is 300px high/wide you only see the top left corner. There's no shrinkage involved here, the transform merely moves where the svg object is shown, it doesn't change what part of it you can see. Think of the svg as being a photo and the transform as rotating/moving that, what you see in the photo will be the same, just moved and rotated.

You could give the svg element width and height values e.g. 350px and then add a scale to the transform to shrink it. Specifying a transform rather than just a -webkit-transform will make the code more cross-browser too.

Comment: If one wants to have the "size to parent" behavior it's always possible to specify `svg { width:100%; height:100% }`. That will make the svg be 100x100px (size of the parent div) in the example http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/d3yS6/. It's also possible to specify `overflow: visible` to overflow the css box (to show the entire svg).